# Pick four cards and compute their sum JAVA

Tags: java

I have most of my program, but I have hit the wall near the end, and I would love the help!

I have to write a program that picks four cards out of a deck of 52 and computes the sum. An Ace, King, Queen, and Jack represent 1, 13, 12, and 11 respectively. The program should display the number of pick that yields the sum of 24.

What I have so far:

```
public class Exercise07_29 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //initialize everything
         int[] deck = new int[52];
         String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
         String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

         //initialize the cards
         for(int i = 0; i< deck.length; i ++)
             deck[i] = i;

         //shuffle the cards
         for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++){

             //generate an index randomly
             int index = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length);
             int temp = deck[i];
             deck[i] = deck[index];
             deck[index] = temp;
         }

         //display the four cards
         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
             String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
             String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
             System.out.println(rank + " of " + suit);
         }
         //initialize Ace Jack Queen King
         int Ace, Jack, Queen, King;

         //Assign a point vale to each
         int[] points = {Ace = 1, Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13};

        //add the cards together and show output

    }
}
```

I tried a loop for the addition, but am having trouble when it comes to adding a random output together....

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: what do you want to show? just the sum of the four cards you have displayed?

Comment: Yes, I need to display four random cards, then add up their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;


public class Exercise07_29 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //initialize everything
        int[] deck = new int[52];
        String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
        String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        List<String> pickedCards = new ArrayList<String>();

        //initialize the cards
        for(int i = 0; i< deck.length; i ++)
            deck[i] = i;

        //shuffle the cards
        for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++){

            //generate an index randomly
            int index = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length);
            int temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[index];
            deck[index] = temp;
        }

        //display the four cards
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
            String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
            System.out.println(rank + " of " + suit);
            pickedCards.add(rank);
        }

        //initialize Ace Jack Queen King
        int Ace, Jack, Queen, King;

        //Assign a point vale to each
        int[] points = {Ace = 1, Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13};

        //add the cards together and show output
        int sum = 0;
        int jack = 11;
        int queen = 12;
        int king = 13;
        int ace = 1;
        Iterator<String> iterator = pickedCards.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {

            String rank = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(rank);
            if(rank.equalsIgnoreCase("Jack")){
            sum = sum+jack;
        }
        else if(rank.equalsIgnoreCase("Queen")){
            sum = sum+queen;
        }
        else if(rank.equalsIgnoreCase("King")){
            sum = sum+king;
        }
        else if(rank.equalsIgnoreCase("Ace")){
            sum = sum+ace;
        } 
        else {
            sum = sum+Integer.parseInt(rank);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of picked cards is : "+sum);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you! this seems to work almost perfectly! Just a little more tweaking, and it should work great! (Ive been working on this particular problem for a while, and was getting really annoyed by it.. :/ )

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your problem here. If it is that you are wondering how to map the Ace, Jack, Queen and King to points then I would suggest the following.

```
Map<Integer, String> cardToPoints = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
cardToPoints.add(1, "Ace");
cardToPoints.add(11, "Jack");
cardToPoints.add(12, "Queen");
cardToPoints.add(13, "King");
```

Then if you need to print the text just search for the number in the map and if there is entry print it otherwise print the number you have.

As variation to this you can create class Card containing points for the card and it string representation and fill the map with this cards.

For example:

```
cardPoints.add(1, new Card(1, "Ace of Spades");
....
cardPoints.add(14, new Card(1, "Ace of Hearts");
cardPoints.add(15, new Card(2, "2 of Hearts");
```

Then just get the card from the map get the points and sum + print the exact cards. Easy and clean( apart of the 52 entries for the map initilization );

Answer (score 0):

Java's an object-oriented language.  You're probably a beginner, but here's an example for you to think about.

```
package cards;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Exercise07_29
 * @author Michael
 * @link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639964/pick-four-cards-and-compute-their-sum-java
 * @since 7/26/2015 1:42 PM
 */
public class Exercise07_29 {

    public static final int NUM_CARDS = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<>();
        int score = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CARDS; ++i) {
            Card card = deck.deal();
            hand.add(card);
            score += card.getRank().getValue();
        }
        System.out.println(hand);
        System.out.println(score);
    }
}


enum SUIT {
    CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE;
}

enum RANK {
    ACE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(11), QUEEN(12), KING(13);

    private final int value;

    RANK(int value) { this.value = value; }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    private final SUIT suit;
    private final RANK rank;

    public Card(SUIT suit, RANK rank) {
        if (suit == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("suit cannot be null");
        if (rank == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("rank cannot be null");
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public SUIT getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public RANK getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card other) {
        if (this.getRank().equals(other.getRank())) {
            return this.getSuit().compareTo(other.getSuit());
        } else {
            return this.getRank().getValue() - other.getRank().getValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Card card = (Card) o;

        return suit == card.suit && rank == card.rank;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = suit.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + rank.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Card{");
        sb.append("suit=").append(suit);
        sb.append(", rank=").append(rank);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

class Deck {
    private List<Card> deck;
    private Random random;

    public Deck() {
        this.init();
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    public Deck(long seed) {
        this.init();
        this.random = new Random(seed);
    }

    private void init() {
        this.deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for (SUIT suit: SUIT.values()) {
            for (RANK rank: RANK.values()) {
                this.deck.add(new Card(suit, rank));
            }
        }
    }

    public Card deal() { return this.deal(true); }

    public Card deal(boolean removeCard) {
        int value = this.random.nextInt(this.deck.size());
        return removeCard ? this.deck.remove(value) : this.deck.get(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, that kinda just made my brain explode. Yes I am a beginner, but your code is amazing! I will probably look over it and strive to figure it out after my semester is over....

Thanks for the help though!