# Pick 4 Cards Homework

Tags: java

Note: This has been solved. I have posted the working code below in a later post.

First off, I know there is a similar question here: [Pick four cards and compute their sum JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639964/pick-four-cards-and-compute-their-sum-java)
However, the outcome of their script is different than what mine needs to be, they are just calculating 4 random cards. I need to find EVERY combination of 4 cards that exists.

I am currently in my first Java programming class. We have covered up to methods and arrays, but nothing about classes and objects yet. So please keep that in mind if you choose to answer.

My homework this week is to write a program that finds every possible combination of 4 cards in a deck of 52 that add up to 24. (with Ace being 1, Jack 11, Queen 12, and King 13) I have posted my code below which I know has some mistakes, it doesn't work right for how I want it to. I am posting here to see if I'm on the right track. My instructor says the correct answer is 12,517, and it's up to us to come up with that answer. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Specific Question as requested - "How can I change my below code that will produce the output of 12,517"

Things I know:

1. I know some numbers are missing in the iterations, the 4th stack resets back to 4 instead of going to 1. I haven't yet figured out how to correct this.
2. I know my deepest For loop will loop the same combination 4 times before continuing... I have NO idea why (or how) it's doing this.

NOTE!: I have output messages in the "calculate" method for debugging. If you want to use them, start then stop the script immediately, that will give you an idea. If you want the program to run till completion, then comment out the 3 output messages in the nested 4 loop.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] deck = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
              1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
              1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
              1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
        int total;


        total = calculate(deck);
        output(total);


    }





    public static int calculate(int[] deck){

       int total = 0;
       int stack1, stack2, stack3, stack4, accumulate;



       for (stack1 = 0; stack1 < 52; stack1++){
           for (stack2 = 1; stack2 < 52; stack2++){
               for (stack3 = 2; stack3 < 52; stack3++){
                   for (stack4 = 3; stack4 < 52; stack4++){
                       accumulate = (deck[stack1] + deck[stack2] + deck[stack3] + deck[stack4]);
                      System.out.println(deck[stack1] + " + " + deck[stack2] + " + " + deck[stack3] + " + " + deck[stack4]);
                       if (accumulate == 24){
                           System.out.println(deck[stack1] + " + " + deck[stack2] + " + " + deck[stack3] + " + " + deck[stack4]);
                           total++;
                           System.out.println("Accumulate is at " + accumulate);
                           System.out.println("Currently at " + total);
                      }


                   }
               }
           }
       }





       return total;
    }   

    public static void output(int total){
        System.out.println ("The total number of card combinations of 4 that \n"
                + "equal 24 is: " + total);





    }



 }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for commentary on your code isn't a suitable question for SO

Comment: Soooooo... asking for help with code isn't allowed? Isn't this *entire forum* designed to help people with their coding?

Comment: there's a help section above, it will tell you what good questions are

Comment: you need to think of it less as a forum and more like wikipedia :)  so questions need to be reasonably useful for anyone, and must have a specific answer

Comment: Well that hasn't been my experience on here. Whenever I need help with code I will google it and 9/10 times the answer will be on this site (usually with a reference to the same project I'm working on). For example, the other post that I linked to, that is the exact same problem (from the same book I'm using) only they were looking for a different result. So I don't know what makes my post so different.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to ask a specific question about your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0; //can also just say int counter; ==> auto intialize to 0
    int d, c, h, s; //diamond, club, heart, spade
    for(d = 1; d < 14; d++) //each suit starts at Ace, or the value of 1
        for(c = 1; c < 14; c++) //each suit ends at 13, or King
            for(h = 1; h < 14; h++)
                for(s = 1; s < 14; s++)
                    if( d + c + h + s == 24 )
                        counter++; 
    System.out.println(counter); //Your total should be your instructor's 12,517
}
```

If I may clarify your question: You do NOT mean to ask for every single "combination" of cards (so printing out all 12,517 possibilities).

Rather, you mean to get the total number of combinations represented by counter.

What my four for loops are doing is very simple: it goes through all the possibilities using Ace as 1 and King as 13. If the sum of the four cards equals ( == ) 24, then add one to the counter.

This will work due to the nature of nested for loops, going through all four sets of 13C1 combinatorics.

I hope this helped!

NOTE: In case you weren't aware: in languages with brackets (Java, C), if you're using a conditional statement or a loop (if/else, while, for) with only one following statement, like in my code, you can omit the brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this code was close to my first attempt. Running this code gets a total of 1,291 combinations. I sent my first attempt to my instructor last week and he replied today that 1,291 was wrong and that I needed to be getting 12,517

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code that produces the correct result. The key was to parent the child stack to the parent stack + 1:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] deck = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
              1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
              1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
              1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};

        int total;

        total = calculate(deck);
        output(total);

    }

    public static int calculate(int[] deck){

       int total = 0;
       int stack1, stack2, stack3, stack4, accumulate;


       for (stack1 = 0; stack1 < 52; stack1++){
           for (stack2 = (stack1 + 1); stack2 < 52; stack2++){
               for (stack3 = (stack2 + 1); stack3 < 52; stack3++){
                   for (stack4 = (stack3 + 1); stack4 < 52; stack4++){
                       accumulate = (deck[stack1] + deck[stack2] + deck[stack3] + deck[stack4]);

                       if (accumulate == 24)
                           total++;

                   }
               }
           }

       }       

       return total;
    }   




    public static void output(int total){
        System.out.println ("The total number of card combinations of 4 that \n"
                + "equal 24 is: " + total);

    }


}
```

Comment: One improvement - once the sum exceeds 24 in any of those loops, you might as well break out of that loop. For example, if stack1, stack2, and stack3 have a value of 24, you might as well not even enter the stack4 loop.  Also, I don't think having each loop end at 52 is accurate.

Comment: Ya, I thought of that, and if this were a program I was writing for a job I would probably do that, but for homework it seems to do the job. As for ending at 52, it actually ends at 51 (52 cards in an array that beings with 0). I could have said <= 51, which may be more accurate.

Comment: What I mean is that if all the loops end at 51, then you're going to be generating a "combination" that has card 51 four times. It's a bug, but it doesn't seem to hurt you since the last 4 cards in the deck always sum to more than 24 and thus will be discarded anyway.

Comment: This is, technically, an N^4 problem. It's very slow in the general case (assume you have 100 decks of weird cards...)  Adding common-sense optimizations demonstrates your acknowledgement of this and mastery of the problem. But don't optimize until the code works.  Hint - arrange the deck differently: 1111,2222,3333 etc.  Now when you exceed 24 you know it isn't going to get better and you can break/skip loops.